# Is it possible to zip the contents of a directory in C#?

Tags: zip, c#

Im developing a c# application which has to zip all the content within a directory..
Is this possible?

thanks

Comment: right, there should be many solutions like here: https://github.com/search?langOverride=&language=C%23&q=zip&repo=&start_value=1&type=Repositories

Comment: @nima Don't tell users to ask elsewhere. Questions can always be migrated. When you tell them to ask somewhere else this will lead to cross posting. In the future just let community members migrate the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.**[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)** supports adding a Directory to a zip file with the `ZipFile.AddDirectory()` methods.

To zip up an entire directory, recursively:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
  zip.UseUnicode= true;  // utf-8
  zip.AddDirectory(@"MyFile");
  zip.Save(ZipFileToCreate);
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, however it is important to note that in later versions of .DotNetZip library, the zip.UseUnicode=true line has been deprecated and so that line is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for class `ZipFile` at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx.

UPDATE: This class is only available in .NET 4.5, which is not installed as part of Windows 7.  You would have to download it from Microsoft.

Comment: This is new in .NET 4.5 and is not available in earlier versions.

Comment: Good point, but .NET 4.5 is available for Windows 7 and earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: Is available doesn't mean "is used". I.e. in your answer you could at least specify that details

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [SevenZipSharp](http://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/) like so:

```
SevenZipCompressor compressor = new SevenZipCompressor();
compressor.CompressDirectory(...);
```